# Inserting a C-String into another C-String

Tags: string, insert, c-strings

We are going over c-strings in my C++ class right now. What is the best way to insert a user entered 
c-string into a specific element in an existing c-string?

Comment: Probably the way that uses stdlib functions (`memcpy` or `memmove`, for example.)

Comment: Google "C++" and "string" the first hit should be a good reference for the standard library.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/
Look among the memberfunctions you should find what you need there and you will benefit from learning to use that resource.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way of doing it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1 = "my text";
    string s2 = " new";
    s1.insert(2,s2);
    cout<<s1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```